# Using ExifLib on remote images

Tags: c#, exif, exiflib

I have an application that displays images that are stored remotely on Twitter, Instagram and Flickr's servers. What I would like is to use the [ExifLib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET-2-0) to extract the Exif information (mainly GPS data) and display them for the image details.

Here is what I have so far:

```
string metaData = string.Empty;
string tagValue = string.Empty;

try
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = wc.DownloadData(imgUrl);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            using (ExifReader reader = new ExifReader(ms))
            {
                if (reader.GetTagValue<string>(ExifTags.GPSAltitude, out tagValue))
                    Log.Debug("GPSAltitude: " + tagValue);

                if (reader.GetTagValue<string>(ExifTags.DateTimeDigitized, out tagValue))
                    Log.Debug("DateTimeDigitized: " + tagValue);

                if (reader.GetTagValue<string>(ExifTags.DateTimeOriginal, out tagValue))
                    Log.Debug("DateTimeOriginal: " + tagValue);

                if (reader.GetTagValue<string>(ExifTags.GPSLatitude, out tagValue))
                    Log.Debug("GPSLatitude: " + tagValue);

                if (reader.GetTagValue<string>(ExifTags.GPSLongitude, out tagValue))
                    Log.Debug("GPSLongitude: " + tagValue);

            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Exception("A problem occurred while fetching Exif data.", ex);
}
```

But for every *imageUrl* that goes through seems to not get past instantiating the **ExifReader** with the image's MemoryStream; it always hits the Exception and indicates that ExifLib could not find Exif data, even when I pick [an image from Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/78314804@N03/12232270725/meta/) that clearly has Exif data.

Am I doing something wrong in the code above or does ExifLib not work on remote images?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking if `imageBytes` actually contains valid data?
Save it to a file and see if repeating your function from an actual file changes anything.
Maybe the download doesn't even succeed, you have a lot of activity in the `try..catch`.

As a workaround first save the data in a temporary file on the server and use that. I know you want to avoid that, but better working than nothing. And log the intermediate results on the server so you can distinguich and debug the many possible defects (like wrong URL or Flickr not wanting you to exceed a certain amount of downloads per minute).